# Select not working in Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: mysql, join, search, yii, yii1.x

I have two related table and I have to display data from both trough a join query.
I have this `GridView` that is "working" when i have to do the search, so that's mean if I have to search into a field from the joined table, it works and shows the right result, but I am not able to show all the column from both table.

Here is the error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'pratiche'. The SQL
>   statement executed was: SELECT pratiche.* FROM `pratiche` `t` LEFT
>   JOIN clienti ON id_cliente = clienti.id LIMIT 10

As you can see there is `t` after `pratiche`, so it fail the query.
What's the problem?

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->select = "pratiche.*,clienti.*";

    $criteria->join='LEFT JOIN clienti ON id_cliente = clienti.id';

    $criteria->compare('id_pratiche',$this->id_pratiche,true);
    //this is the fild that should be shown(from the joined table)
    $criteria->compare('codice_fiscale',$this->codice_fiscale,true);

    $criteria->select = "pratiche.*";
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Do you use table prefix for your tables?

Comment: @rob006 not, but i understood why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Wrong way to set the criteria:

```
$criteria->select=array('id_pratiche','data_creazione','stato_pratica','nome','cognome');
```

Comment: what about selecting columns from right table? because select columns from join table is not showing.